# Select multiple values from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables: joined_schedules, schedules, users

```
joined_schedules has: schedule_id, user_id, permission
schedules has: schedule_id, schedule_name
users has: user_id, name
```

permission can either be 0, 1, 2 (0 is an owner, 1 is an administrator and 2 is a regular user)

I am trying to select all of a users schedules where the permission is 2.  I have no problem with this but I also need the owner of the schedule (permission = 0) in the same query.  I am having trouble with this part.

The problem with this sql is that it only selects the schedule_id and the schedule_name.  I also need the name of the user where their permission = 0 for the same schedule.

```
SELECT joined_schedules.schedule_id, schedules.schedule_name
    FROM joined_schedules
    INNER JOIN schedules
        ON joined_schedules.schedule_id = schedules.schedule_id
    WHERE joined_schedules.user_id = '$id'
    AND joined_schedules.permission = 2
```

EDIT: I have also tried

```
SELECT joined_schedules.schedule_id, schedules.schedule_name, users.name
    FROM joined_schedules
    INNER JOIN schedules
        ON joined_schedules.schedule_id = schedules.schedule_id
        INNER JOIN users
            ON users.user_id = joined_schedules.schedule_id
            AND joined_schedules.permission = 0
                WHERE joined_schedules.user_id = '$id'
    AND joined_schedules.permission = 2
```

Comment: You see to understand `join`s.  Try joining in the `users` table.

Comment: I have tried join the users table (edit) but I am not sure about the AND joined_schedules.permission = 0 / AND joined_schedules.permission = 2

Comment: You could put the `AND joined_schedules.permission = 0` and `AND joined_schedules.permission = 2` in your where clause instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by joining back on the `joined_schedules` table where permission = 0:

```
SELECT joined_schedules.schedule_id, schedules.schedule_name, u.name
FROM joined_schedules
    INNER JOIN schedules
        ON joined_schedules.schedule_id = schedules.schedule_id 
            AND joined_schedules.permission = 2
    LEFT JOIN joined_schedules jsOwner 
        ON jsOwner.schedule_id = schedules.schedule_id 
            AND jsOwner.permission = 0
    LEFT JOIN users u 
        ON u.user_id = jsOwner.user_id 
WHERE joined_schedules.user_id = '$id'
```